# Issue with deploying ejabberd server in GCP and accessing it's service using ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I deployed the ejabberd/ecs dokcer image in GCP with service type as node port and tried to access it using the ingress, but it is not working and I am not able to access the service using ingress.
I added another service for the same deployment with service type as Load Balancer and now I able to access the ejabberd server directly from the service. I don't what is right way to add an ingress for the ejabberd service.

Below are my yaml files:
***Deployment.yaml***

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ejabberd-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ejabberd-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ejabberd-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ejabberd-container
          image: ejabberd/ecs
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5222
            - containerPort: 5443
            - containerPort: 4369
```

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ejabberd-service
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    # cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"5443":"ejabberd-backend-config"}}'
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default":"ejabberd-backend-config"}'
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5222
    protocol: TCP
    name: xmpp
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 5443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    app: ejabberd-deployment
  type: NodePort
```

**Backendconfig.yaml**

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: ejabberd-backend-config
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 15
    port: 5443
    type: HTTPS
    requestPath: /ws
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 3
    timeoutSec: 15
```

**Ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ejabberd-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - dev-chat.mydomain.com
      secretName: ssl-secretname
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: ejabberd-service
      port:
        number: 443
  rules:
    - host: dev-chat.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /* 
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ejabberd-service
                port:
                  number: 443
```

Above are my yaml files. I want to access the ejabberd service from the ingress URL. Kindly assist me with the difficulties I am facing here and suggest any alternatives if available.

**Ingress UI:**
[image]

**Output on hitting ingress endpoints:**
[image]

Comment: Generally looks correct. Do you see Application Load Balancer created for the ingress in the UI console? Any interesting info there?

Comment: Yes, Load Balancer is created in the ingress.

Comment: Great, so when you hit this endpoint what exactly is happening - connection timeout or some other error?

Comment: When I hit the ingress endpoints I am getting 502 error.

Comment: Most likely the issue is because you're trying to have SSL termination on XMPP - which is likely not supported by GKE ingress - see here for some related problem of a different ingress and some workarounds - https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/636